# Quicksight: Calculation between two dates

Tags: mysql, date, business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight

I work with hotel reservations with the following main fields:

- reservation id
- check-in date
- check-out date
- Nights: `dateDiff({check-in_date},{check-out_date},"DD")`

The thing is I have the total nights per reservation but I would like to have a table with the total nights by each date. Data example:

```
"booking_id","check_in date","check_out date","Nights"
"1010354582","2022-01-01","2022-01-02",1
"1010364988","2022-01-01","2022-01-03",2
"1010366636","2022-01-01","2022-01-03",2
"1010366752","2022-01-01","2022-01-02",1
"1010367996","2022-01-01","2022-01-04",3
```

And the result I want:

```
"stay_date","Nights"
"2022-01-01",5
"2022-01-02",3
"2022-01-03",1
```

How can I replace the check_in  of the original dataset with a new "stay_date" which sum all the reservations that go through the same day of stay?

It can be solved directly with Quicksight or I have to do a different query on the database (Mysql)?

Comment: Could you post your data as text instead of an image?

Comment: Done @Zakaria. I re-edit the post without image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a different query on Mysql. You need to create a table called `dates` with one field  `date`. You need to put a date there for all days you might need to report (example pre populate from 2020 to 2030).

Then you would need to use a custom sql query to have a join
that is like this:

```
SELECT
  dates.date AS stay_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT booking_id) as Nights
FROM  
  dates LEFT JOIN bookings
    ON 
      dates.date BETWEEN bookings.check_in_date AND bookings.check_out_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
      AND bookings.check_in_date <= bookings.check_out_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY 
  dates.date
```